# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render when adding a hook component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useInput hook component that works like this:

```
useInput(
    <input placeholder="phone number" />,
    "phone"
  )
```

It gets an (input,inputName) and returns a hooked input component.
When I want to dynamically change the visibility of existing input in my view, I get an error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

```
{this.state.showMyInput && useInput(
        <input placeholder="phone number" />,
        "phone"
      )
}
```

Comment: Would you mind providing the code of your `useInput` hook?

Comment: You need to use hooks at the top of components

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks) you can't use a hook with conditionnal operator.

You can call hook all the time and store the result in a variable, and just condition the render instead.

```
const input = useInput(input, inputName);
...    
{this.state.showMyInput && input}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me fix this weird bug that I had. A useState hook was being created inside a function which was being executed conditionally.

Answer (score 7):

As per the react docs, you shouldn't invoke hooks inside a conditional statement. Instead, use the conditional inside your hook: [As explained here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation)

Answer (score 2):

my problem was that I had used the `useState` hooks after a return statement on my code, like:

```
function myComponenet () {
   if(loading) {return <Loading/>}

   const [myVar, setMyVar] = React.useState({})

   // my main component UI begins here

   <View>.....</View>
}
```

I had to move this `const [myVar, setMyVar] = React.useState({})` line, above the `if statement` and that solved my problem