# How to fix Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render when using SWR with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, swr

I a having an issues using SWR with useEffect hook.

I am getting the error Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

My code is as follows:

```
const { id } = router.query;
  const { data: recipe } = useRecipe(id);

  if (recipe) {
    useEffect(() => {
      if (typeof post.title === "string") {
        setTitle(recipe.title);
      }
    }, [recipe]);
  }

  if (!recipe) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
```

useRecipe is a custom SWR hook that works perfect, as when I comment the useEffect out the data loads as expected. If I move the useEffect above the conditional recipe check i get recipe is undefined as you would expect.

I'd love to understand why I am getting the error 'Rendered more hooks than during the previous render'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendered more hooks than during the previous render when adding a hook component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56143502/rendered-more-hooks-than-during-the-previous-render-when-adding-a-hook-component)

Comment: Hi @juliomalves, appreciate the help. It partially does, I still wouldn't of been able to to figure out a fix without the below answer. Great to now know that hooks cannot be conditionally rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. you can read more in the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

In your case, you can do:

```
const { id } = router.query;
const { data: recipe } = useRecipe(id);

useEffect(() => {
  if (recipe && typeof post.title === "string") {
    setTitle(post.title);
  }
}, [recipe]);

if (!recipe) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}

return ....;
```

Comment: Thanks @Nir, appreciate it, it worked perfectly. Just for anyone else looking at this is  should be {data: recipe} = useRecipe and recipe.title. Thats my mistake, I wrote post instead of recipe in my initial question, I've updated my initial question for clarity.